# Why is typing Ctrl + D in my android studio deleting my current line instead of duplicating it?

Tags: android, android-studio, keyboard-shortcuts

Android documentation shows no changes in the keyboard shortcuts.

Expected duplication of a line of code, recently since a few days, that has changed. my line of code on pressing `ctrl+D` gets deleted instead of duplicating it. and my `ctrl+Y` is not doing any work. Can I know what has changed?

Comment: Have you updated Android Studio "since a few days"?

Comment: NO. I did not update my android studio recently.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please check this,

```
1) File -> Settings
2) Go to Keymap and select the key map that you want to use. 
3) Restart IDE
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

please change the setting of the android studio. file menu inside File -> Settings

Answer (score 0):

change keymap to NetBeans IDE

1. File -> Settings
2. Go to Keymap and select NetBeans IDE.
3. Restart IDE